# Check if a record exists return always false if the fields is null

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

So I have the following situation:

[image]

as you can see some fields are null, so I want check before insert the record is this already exists inside the table `goal`, the record that I'm going to insert contains exactly the same structure of the record already avaialble in the table.

This is my code:

```
public bool CheckGoalExist(Goal goal, Goal.GoalType type, int matchId)
{
    using (MySqlConnection connection = new DBConnection().Connect())
    {
        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goal " +
                "WHERE player_marker_id = @player_marker_id AND " +
                "team_id = @team_id AND " +
                "player_assist_id = @player_assist_id AND " +
                "match_id = @match_id AND " +
                    "minute = @minute AND " +
                    "type = @type";

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@team_id", goal.TeamId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player_marker_id", goal.MarkerPlayer.Id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player_assist_id", goal.AssistPlayer?.Id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@match_id", matchId);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@minute", goal.Minute);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", GetGoalTypeId(type));

            return Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
}
```

this will return `false` but the value of `goal` are this:

```
TeamId = 95
MarkerPlayer.Id = 122
AssistPlaer = null
matchId = 2564940
Minute = 82'
Type = 5
```

why return false?

Comment: I don't know much about MySQL, but just a hint by looking at `goal.AssistPlayer?.Id`. In many SQL engines, `null = null` is false

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/18/why-null-never-compares-false-to-anything-in-sql/ that nicely explains your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `AssistPlaer` is `null`, then you cannot use `=`.  You need to check if the parameter is `null` first.  Here's a common approach with an `or` statement:

```
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goal " +
            "WHERE player_marker_id = @player_marker_id AND " +
            "team_id = @team_id AND " +
            "(@player_assist_id is null or player_assist_id = @player_assist_id) AND " +
            "match_id = @match_id AND " +
                "minute = @minute AND " +
                "type = @type";
```

You may need to do that for other potential `null` values as well.

Comment: `System.DBNull.Value` instead of null?

Comment: i typed the answer almost equal to yours, but posted 3 minutes after, was testing it - likeminded ones

Comment: @Dr.Snail I thought `mysql` was more lenient with `null` values.  But in case it isn't, OP can use `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@player_assist_id", ((object)goal.AssistPlayer?.Id) ?? DBNull.Value);`

Comment: @sgeddes yes I can use this with a ternary condition, but I though that mysql handle the null itself, I though bad

Answer (score 1):

since "AssistPlaer" is "NULL", the query in SQL cannot use the equal operator "=", but must compare to "NULL" using the "IS" or "IS NOT".

your query states:

```
player_assist_id = @player_assist_id
```

but "NULL" values do not respond to equal operators, the only way to test if it's null or not is this:

```
player_assist_id IS NULL
```

so in your query you could bypass that using something like:

```
(@player_assist_id IS NULL AND player_assist_id IS NULL) OR (player_assist_id = @player_assist_id)
```

apply this behavior to any column that can contain "NULL".

Answer (score 0):

if you don't know the attribute value whether it is NULL or not then you can use IFNULL String Function so that it will replace the NULL value with 0 or some other value defined by you in that particular column.